# Can I use iptables to limit port's outgoing bandwidth?

Tags: linux, iptables, traffic-shaping

I want to limit my linux server port 8080 at speed 500KB/s, can I do this with iptables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you specifically avoiding "tc" (traffic control: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/index.html)?  I think "tc" is the more appropriate tool for that job.